# Put some text under a relation symbol

Tags: math-mode

How to put some text under a binary operation symbol?

For example like this - the text "m" under the symbol "=".

[image]

About using \scriptscriptstyle. This command don't give the disired result. Because, space between "m" and "=" is too big. For example

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    $A \underset{m}{=} B$ $A \underset{\scriptscriptstyle{m}}{=} B$
    \end{document}
```

[image]

There is the same vertical size of formula in both cases.

Comment: the `stackengine` package will allow you to tailor the undersetting distance.  For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132843/inline-underset-spilling-over-to-next-line/132845#132845

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with `\underset`. Of course if the text is wider than the `=` sign, you should use `\clap`, or `\mathclap` if it's a formula in order to ensure proper spacing of the `=` sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ A \underset{m}{=} B \]%
\[ A \underset{\mathclap{m + n}}{=} B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I often combine this with `\scriptscriptstyle` to get these as amsll as possible so the down disturb too much

Comment: @daleif: Very useful observation. That's indeed another possibility I also sometimes use. It's all a matter of context.

Comment: About using \scriptscriptstyle. This command don't give the disired result. Because, space between "m" and "=" is too big. For example
$A \underset{m}{=} B$ $A \underset{\scriptscriptstyle{m}}{=} B$
There is the same vertical size of formula in both cases.

Comment: @Alex E.: You can cheat with this code `A \underset{\mathclap{{}^{m + n}}}{=} B`.